# Getting this error when usin newthon-raphson: invalid value encountered in double_scalars

Tags: python, numpy

I got this error when I try to use some numbers on my code, I ask the user to enter the first angle, so python use Newton-raphson to give a new number. But when I enter small numbers o even some random numbers I get that error. Here's my code, this is my first time using python:

```
import numpy as np
def cos(x):
    return np.cos(np.radians(x))
def sin(x):
    return np.sin(np.radians(x))

D = 5
Q = 18

def poli(x):
    y= (2/D**2)*((((D*(Q**2))/9.81)*(sin(x)))**0.33) + 0.25*sin(2*x) + 0.5*x - x
    return (y)

def deri(x):
    d=0.0087*cos(2*x) + ((0.0155*(Q**0.66)*cos(x))/(D*9.81*((D*sin(x))/9.81)*0.67)) - 0.5
    return (d)

print ("Método de Newton-Raphson")
x = float(input('Introduce el valor de inicio '))
erroru=0.001
raiz=[ ]
raiz.insert(0,0)
i=0
error=1
while abs(error) > erroru:
    x1=x-(poli(x)/deri(x))
    raiz.append(x1)
    i=i+1
    x=x1
    error=(raiz[i]-raiz[i-1])/raiz[i]
    print (x)
```

I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

the np.cos and np.sin are referring to radians. no need to convert

```
import numpy as np
def cos(x):
    return np.cos(x)
def sin(x):
    return np.sin(x)

D = 5
Q = 18

def poli(x):
    y= (2/D**2)*((((D*(Q**2))/9.81)*(sin(x)))**0.33) + 0.25*sin(2*x) + 0.5*x - x
    return (y)

def deri(x):
    d=0.0087*cos(2*x) + ((0.0155*(Q**0.66)*cos(x))/(D*9.81*((D*sin(x))/9.81)*0.67)) - 0.5
    return (d)

print ("Método de Newton-Raphson")
x = float(input('Introduce el valor de inicio '))
erroru=0.001
raiz=[ ]
raiz.insert(0,0)
i=0
error=1
while abs(error) > erroru:
    x1=x-(poli(x)/deri(x))
    raiz.append(x1)
    i=i+1
    x=x1
    error=(raiz[i]-raiz[i-1])/raiz[i]
    print (x)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have `numpy.float64` type in your code and the float64 are like c float, and overload all operations (including) power to work as such. 
You error occurs when you do

```
(value ** 0.33)
```

where value is a negative `numpy.float64` type.

Value ** 0.33 is *probably* an imaginary number. Python numpy float64s are real, so the above is an invalid expression (python float can handle that).
To make it work you could cast that to `float`(but the final result could be incorrect)

You can convert your poli function as such:

```
def poli(x):
    y= (2/D**2)*(float(((D*(Q**2))/9.81)*(sin(x)))**0.33) + 0.25*sin(2*x) + 0.5*x - x
    return (y)
```

After that you get another error, but that is another story

> TypeError: ufunc 'radians' not supported for the input types, and the
>   inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to
>   the casting rule ''safe''